# Getting exception in dynamic jaxb

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, eclipselink

I am getting following exception , i need to create dynamic xml from xsd for which I am following the eclipse link [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/jpatoxml006.htm):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.plugins.BeanValidationPlugin could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:910)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:351)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:77)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:337)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.<init>(ParserContext.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.<init>(XSOMParser.java:125)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:420)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:428)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:509)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata.getJavaModelInput(SchemaMetadata.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext$SchemaContextInput.createContextState(DynamicJAXBContext.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext.<init>(DynamicJAXBContext.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(DynamicJAXBContextFactory.java:279)
    at com.accenture.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/model/CPropertyVisitor2
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CPropertyVisitor2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

My Main class code is :

```
package com.accenture;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Marshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.noCorrectnessCheck", "true");

        FileInputStream xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/com/accenture/customer.xsd");
        DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream,
                new MyEntityResolver(), null, null);

        DynamicEntity customer = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.example.Customer");
        customer.set("name", "Jane Doe");

        DynamicEntity address = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.example.Address");
        address.set("street", "1 Any Street").set("city", "Any Town");
        customer.set("address", address);

        JAXBMarshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

    }
}
```

Entity resolver code is :

```
package com.accenture;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

class MyEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {

    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        // Imported schemas are located in ext\appdata\xsd\

        // Grab only the filename part from the full path
        String filename = new File(systemId).getName();

        // Now prepend the correct path
        String correctedId = "src/main/java/com/accenture/" + filename;

        InputSource is = new InputSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(correctedId));
        is.setSystemId(correctedId);

        return is;
    }

}
```

My aim is to create an XML dynamically from referencing an XSD. Easiest way i found was eclipse link but it is giving me error, can someone please guide me how to correct this or any other simpler way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for any jar version mismatch

Comment: @TinoMThomas can u explain more please? only jar I have added in the project is the eclipselink.jar version 2.7 so which jar version is mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the following jars and it will work:

```
1. jaxb-core_2.2.11.v201407311112.jar
2. jaxb-xjc_2.2.11.v201407311112.jar
```